# Wie wird das Adjektiv zum Buchhalter richtig betont?

Tags: pronunciation, stress

Warum wird eigentlich das gute und urdeutsche Wort

> buchhalterisch

(Also das Adjektiv zu *Buchhalter* bzw. *Buchhaltung*)

das meinem Sprachgefühl nach auf der ersten Silbe betont gehört, von vielen Menschen wie ein Fremdwort auf der dritten Silbe (buchhaltérisch) betont?

Gibt es dafür, ausser dass es exotisch und möglicherweise fachmännisch klingt, irgendeinen einleuchtenden Grund? Ist das möglicherweise sogar richtig? Oder doch nur Imponiergehabe?

"Bäuerlich" oder "ärztlich", "haushalterisch" oder möglicherweise sogar "verwalterisch" spricht man ja auch nicht so schräg betont.

Ich habe eine ähnliche Betonung sonst nur noch (allerdings wesentlich selténer) bei der "evangelisch-luthérischen Kirche" gehört und finde sie dort genauso falsch, komisch und ungewöhnlich. Der Mann hieß Martin Luther und war kein Franzose.

Comment: Mehr als Du je wissen wolltest: http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/buchhalterisch-betonung.php

Mit profunden Argumente für (auch) buchhaltérisch.

Comment: Sehr viel mehr als ich je wissen wollte - Danke dafür. Du hast es nicht gemacht, aber: Für mich sind viele der dort in 26 Minuten aufgestellten "Wahrheiten" allerdings ein bisschen an den Haaren herbeigezogen - Zum Beispiel: "Buchhalterisch ist ein Fremdwort, weil es eine wörtliche Übersetzung aus dem Italienischen ist". Alleine die Prämisse, dass es mehr Leute gäbe, die "buchhaltérisch" statt "buchhalterisch" sagen würde - Dazu fehlt mir der Beweis. Meiner Erfahrung nach ist das eher andersrum. Zwar blumig erklärt, für mich aber nicht schlüssig.

Comment: - aber vielleicht kann es das auch gar nicht sein.

Comment: Aus den meisten (allen?) der bei belleslettres angeführten Gründen müsste es im Übrigen auch "haushaltérisch" heissen. Die würden für dieses Wort ebenfalls zutreffen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In den verschiedenen Bänden des Duden findet man für das Wort *[buchhalterisch](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/buchhalterisch)* ausschließlich die Betonung auf der ersten Silbe:

> bu̲chhalterisch

Diese Betonung entspricht der Standardlautung, welche zum Beispiel auch die Aussprache geschulter Rundfunksprecher wiedergibt. Sie erhebt allerdings keinen Anspruch darauf, die vielfältigen Varianten der gesprochenen Sprache vollständig widerzuspiegeln. Daher ist nicht auszuschließen, dass es regionale Abweichungen von dieser Betonung gibt.

Ebenso findet man auch für viele andere Adjektive, die auf *-terisch* enden, keine Betonung der Silbe *-te-*:

> ạltväterisch
>   a̲u̲sbeuterisch
>   a̲u̲ßenseiterisch
>   dịchterisch
>   fẹchterisch
>   fre̲i̲beuterisch
>   gebi̲e̲terisch
>   gestạlterisch
>   gịchterisch
>   ha̲a̲rspalterisch
>   ha̲u̲shälterisch
>   ho̲chverräterisch
>   lạndesverräterisch
>   le̲i̲setreterisch
>   me̲u̲terisch
>   rạppenspalterisch
>   sạchwalterisch
>   spạlterisch
>   verrä̲terisch
>   zụ̈chterisch
>   zu̲hälterisch

Dagegen werden einige Fremdwörter und entsprechende fachsprachliche Fügungen tatsächlich auf der der Silbe *-te-* betont:

> alloste̲risch
>   anikte̲risch
>   aste̲risch
>   dysente̲risch
>   ente̲risch
>   gastroente̲risch
>   esote̲risch
>   exote̲risch
>   hyste̲risch
>   ikte̲risch
>   klimakte̲risch
>   myente̲risch
>   neote̲risch
>   ste̲risch

Das in der Frage zum Vergleich genannte Adjektiv *lutherisch* wird laut dem Duden im kirchlichen Sprachgebrauch heute im Allgemeinen auf der ersten Silbe betont. Die auf der lateinischen Form *luthericus* beruhende Betonung *luthe̲risch* ist seltener und gilt als veraltet oder wird – auch ironisch – zur Kennzeichnung einer stark orthodoxen Auffassung verwendet.

Comment: Danke für die Bemerkung zur "luthérisch-orthodoxen" Glaubensrichtung. Wusste ich nicht, bzw. ist bei uns im Süden nicht gebräuchlich.

Comment: Es gibt auch weit weniger exotische Worte bei denen das abgeleitete Adjektiv anders als das Stammwort ausgesprochen wird. Spontan fallen mit Viktória / viktoriánisch und Kalkulátor / kalkulatórisch ein.

Comment: @Ingmar - Richtig - deine Beispiele sind aber beides *Fremdworte* - Die dürfen anders als deutsche Wörter betont werden - Und ich habe dies extra in meiner Frage betont.

Comment: Ich wiederhole meinen Link zu http://belleslettres.eu/artikel/buchhalterisch-betonung.php Auf die Fremdworteigenschaft kommt's eigentlich nicht an.

Comment: @Ingmar - Wenn es nicht auf die Fremdworteigenschaft ankäme,  dann müsste belleslettres wohl auch nicht behaupten, dass buchhalterisch ein Fremdwort sei? (Was ich anzweifle) Hier widerspricht sich für mich was.

Comment: Bisher gefällt mir deine Antwort am besten - Allerdings enthält sie keine Antwort auf das "*warum* betonen das manche Leute wie ein Fremdwort"

Comment: Ein weiterer Beleg für die dürftige Qualität des Duden. In der Fachsprache der Buchhalter, die sicher häufiger über buchhalterisches sprechen als jeder sonst, wird es auf der 3. Silbe betont.

Answer (score 8):

Ich spreche das Wort im fachsprachlichen Kontext auch so aus. Mein österreichisches Wörterbuch nennt es "veraltet", aber in der Fachsprache hat sich das, zumal in Österreich, durchaus so erhalten.

Ich würde sogar einen Bedeutungsunterschied zwischen búchhalterisch und buchhaltérisch behaupten: ersteres bezieht sich als Adjektiv auf den Buchhalter, letzters auf die Vorgänge der Buchführung.

Comment: Den vermuteten Bedeutungsunterschied zwischen den beiden Varianten finde ich interessant - Findest du dafür einen Beleg?

Comment: Nein, das ist nur persönliches (muttersprachliches) Sprachempfinden.

Comment: "Österreichisches Wörterbuch": Ist die Betonung möglicherweise ein Austriazismus? @HubertSchölnast schein auch den Standpunkt zu haben, dass die auf der 3. Silbe betonte Version die gebräuchlichere wäre.

Comment: Das kann ich nicht ausschließen, aber ich halte es eher für eine fachsprachliche Besonderheit.

Answer (score 7):

Auch wenn es für manches Ohr bescheuert klingen mag, ich kenne ausschließlich die Aussprache, welche die 3. Silbe betont, also *buchhaltērisch*. Auch wenn ich selbst kein Buchhalter bin, habe ich als Entwickler von Warenwirtschafts-Lösungen häufig mit Menschen zu tun, welche im Bereich Buchführung tätig sind. Ich habe noch keinen getroffen, der das anders betont.

Answer (score 2):

Ich kann nichts dazu sagen, wie die Aussprachevariante "buchhaltérisch" konkret entstanden ist  und wie sie sich verbreitet hat. Ich kann aber folgende Beobachtungen aus dem Alltag und der konkreten Wortverwendung beitragen:

1) Das Wort wird so gut wie nur von Finanzmenschen verwendet (in der Geschäftswelt wie in der staatlichen Verwaltung). Das ist aber auch kein Wunder, denn weder "búchhalterisch" noch "buchhaltérisch" haben viel Nutzwert in anderen Zusammenhängen als eben der Buchhaltung, und die gibt es in Firmen sowie in der Verwaltung. Wer sich damit nicht befasst, braucht das Wort einfach nicht.

2) Wo immer ich auf "buchhaltérisch" stieß, war es für mich der Versuch des Sprechers, ein an sich schon von vielen als dröge empfundenes Thema durch eine Prise sachten Sprachhumors ein bisschen aufzulockern, indem man aus dem langweiligen Wort "búchhalterisch" ein Pseudofremdwort macht.

**Vermutungen:**

Vielleicht spielt auch der Neid bei der Zunft der Buchhalter eine Rolle. Viele Professionen haben tolle Wörter für die Sachen, mit denen sie sich beschäftigen... "pychopharmakológisch", "numérisch", "polymérisch", "phonemátisch", "reduktionístisch" und so weiter (siehe auch die Liste in der Antwort von Loong). Vielleicht wollen die Buchhalter, tief in sich drinnen, einfach auch so ein tolles Wort. Oder sie spielen wenigstens damit.

Mir ist nie in den Sinn gekommen, dass jemand, der "buchhaltérisch" sagt, dies ernst meinen könnte.

(Ein tolles Wort, das Buchhalter und andere Geldbetreuer in der öffentlichen Verwaltung gerne verwenden, ist natürlich *Kameralístik*. Es kommt immer gut, das in eine Konversation einfließen zu lassen. So gut wie kein Außenstehender kann etwas damit anfangen, aber es klingt fachmännisch.)

Comment: Um ein paar Vorurteile aufzuwärmen: Es ist eine Berufskrankheit des Buchhalters, dass er alles bierernst sehen muss - Also, nein: Die meinen das todernst, da ist kein bißchen Selbstironie dabei. Ich habe allerdings den blassen Verdacht, dass du mit dem Rest wahrscheinlich leider recht hast.

Answer (score 1):

Bitte entscheide dich, wonach du fragst. In der Überschrift fragst du:

> Wie wird das Adjektiv zum Buchhalter “richtig” betont?

Im Fließtext stellst du aber eine ganz andere Frage, nämlich:

> Warum wird eigentlich das [...] Wort buchhalterisch [...] auf der dritten Silbe [...] betont?

Das sind zwei verschiedene Fragen, ich will dennoch versuchen, beide zu beantworten:

---

### 1.

> Warum wird es (von manchen) auf der dritten Silbe betont?

Bernd hört, dass es Anna so ausspricht, und glaubt entweder, dass es so richtig ist, oder dass es zumindest eine korrekte Variante ist. Daher spricht es auch Bernd (manchmal) so aus.

Claudia hört, dass es Anna und Bernd so aussprechen, und glaubt entweder, dass es so richtig ist, oder dass es zumindest eine korrekte Variante ist. Daher spricht es auch Claudia (manchmal) so aus.

Daniel hört, ...

Ich glaube, du erkennst das Muster. Warum Anna diese Aussprache gewählt hat, ist letztlich irrelevant. Vielleicht hat sie sich geirrt, oder sie wollte Bernd verwirren, oder sie hat einen Scherz gemacht, den Bernd nicht verstanden hat.

Was ich sagen will:
Das Wort wird von einigen Menschen manchmal so ausgesprochen, weil es auch andere Menschen manchmal so aussprechen.

---

### 2.

> Ist das richtig?

Regeln, die vorgeben zu bestimmen, was richtig und was falsch ist, geben in Wahrheit nur wieder, wie die Sprache in der jüngeren Vergangenheit von der Mehrheit verwendet wurde. Aber eine lebende Sprache lebt eben, und verändert sich ständig. Das führt unweigerlich dazu, dass der tatsächliche Gebrauch von den festgeschriebenen Regeln abweicht. Anfangs wird diese Abweichung entweder nicht wahrgenommen, oder als Fehler angesehen. Je mehr Menschen aber diesen »Fehler« machen, desto weniger falsch ist es.

Heute regt sich niemand mehr darüber auf, dass gewisse Dinge »Sinn machen«. Noch vor 15 oder 20 Jahren wäre man dafür gescholten worden, und hätte gesagt bekommen, dass es »sinnvoll sein« heißen muss.

Und so entstehen neben den etablierten Versionen neue Versionen, die mehr oder weniger häufig verwendet werden.

Wenn ein renommierter Wörterbuchverlag eine Variante durch Erwähnung in der neuesten Auflage adelt, ist diese Variante mehr oder weniger offiziell richtig. Aber der Verlag würde die neue Variante nicht in sein wertvolles Buch aufnehmen, wenn er sie für falsch hielte. Daher muss die Variante auch vor Veröffentlichung in einem Nachschlagewerk zumindest »ein bisschen« richtig gewesen sein.

Kürzer formuliert:
Wenn es genügend viele Menschen so aussprechen, ist es nicht ganz falsch.

Comment: Nachdem gleich vier Leute meine Antwort negativ bewertet haben, würde ich gerne wissen, was daran falsch ist. Trifft das, was ich geschrieben habe, denn nicht zu? Sind das keine Antworten auf die gestellten Fragen?

Comment: Ich fürchte, dass Du mit dieser vermeintlichen Nicht-Antwort völlig recht hast: Es gibt zz. im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch keine richtige(re) oder falsche(re) Variante. Außer dass buchhaltérisch völlig bescheuert klingt, aber das ist meine persönliche Ansicht. ;-)

Comment: Ich weiß nicht, ob die Antwort falsch oder richtig ist. Ich habe den ersten Absatz gelesen, danach noch einmal die erste Version der Frage, und dann habe ich kopfschüttelnd die Seite verlassen.

Comment: @CarstenS: Kopfschütteln ist völlig ok. Aber wenn eine Antworten genau auf die gestellte Frage eingeht und diese auch (wie ich glaube) völlig richtig beantwortet, finde ich es weniger ok, wenn diese Antwort dann abgestraft wird weil sie jemanden, der die Antwort gar nicht bis zum Ende gelesen hat, zum Schütteln von Körperteilen veranlasst.

Comment: Ich habe –1 gegeben, weil ich deine Antwort auf die erste Teilfrage für falsch halte. In der Regel lasse ich mich nicht von Anderen beeinflussen, wie ich etwas ausspreche, insbesondere nicht, wenn es ein Datenpunkt ist. Das geschieht bereits im Unterbewusstsein. Es gibt viele englische Wörter, die ich falsch ausspreche, weil sie falsch in meinem Unterbewusstsein verankert sind (ich habe sie beim ersten Mal lesen falsch dechiffriert), deswegen hat aber noch niemand angefangen, diese Wörter genauso falsch auszusprechen. Der einzige Kommentar dazu jemals war ‘it’s so cute how you say “suicidal”.’

Comment: Speziell bei diesem Begriff habe ich den Eindruck, dass die Menschen, die "buchhalterisch" so betonen wie gefragt, mir damit etwas sagen wollen - Schliesslich sind das meistens "Finanzmenschen". Ich würde damit an sich das "zufällig anders und dann hat's jeder nachgemacht" wie in deinem ersten Antwortteil für diesem speziellen Fall ausschliessen, sondern halte diese ungewöhnliche Betonung für "volle Absicht".

Comment: @tofro    Ja, "buchhaltérisch" wird vor allem von Finanzmenschen (aus Geschäftswelt und staatlicher Verwaltung) verwendet. Doch auch "buchhalterisch" wird praktisch nur von solchen Leuten verwendet. Denn wer sonst sollte das Wort je brauchen? Die Hausfrau nicht, die Kinderärztin nicht, die Chemikerin nicht, die Opernsängerin nicht, die Geschichtsprofessorin nicht...