# Stress in Composita & Southern versus Northern German variants of Standard German in Stress

Tags: pronunciation, standard-german, compound, accent, low-german

I (as a Bavarian native speaker) notice that Northern Germans when speaking standard German almost consistently use a different stress in composita, which can sound illogical to the Southern German ear. For example "Altersruhesitz" which would be pronounced in the South like "Àltersruhesitz", with a primary stress on the "a" and possibly a secondary stress at the "i", while Northern speakers seem to prefer "Altersrùhesitz" with the stress at the "u" like here at [14:37](https://www.ardmediathek.de/ard/video/tatort/tatort-es-lebe-der-koenig/das-erste/Y3JpZDovL2Rhc2Vyc3RlLmRlL3RhdG9ydC8yNTExM2NiNS1hODczLTRkMmMtODAyNi1kNGQxYWVkMmZlY2U/)
. The latter sounds in the Southern ear as if there is a range of things you can have if you are old and one of them is a special "-ruhesitz", while the (in my ears correct) pronunciation "Àltersruhesitz" suggests it's the "-ruhesitz" if you become elderly, as it should be. I could give plenty of other examples for that. The all work in the same way. My main questions would be:

1. What is the "correct" standard pronunciation (in the "deutsche Bühnensprache", or according the "Ausspracheduden"), and why?
2. Why do the Southern and Northern variants differ in that respect?

My simple hypotheses would be that in the Northern variants we hear an echo of the Lower German languages which do much less discriminate between lengths and stresses as the Southern variants do and that the southern Variant should be grammatically more correct than the northern one as "Standard German" is a Roofing of the Southern Languages/Dialects.

Curious and grateful about any takes on that!

---

Edit:

Some examples :

1. Judith Rakers, Tagesschau 20:00, 23.12.2020 [*Coronavari**a**nte*](https://youtu.be/I42MxKqvzME?t=499)
2. Britta Hilpert, Heute Journal 21:45, 29.12.2020 [*lebensgef**ä**hrlich*](https://www.zdf.de/nachrichten/heute-journal/elend-auf-der-balkanroute-100.html) @01:48
3. Frank Jordans, RKI Pressekonferenz,14.0.1.2021 [*Impfsch**u**tzverordnung*](https://youtu.be/KdYq3KfPn5U?t=1104)@18:28
4. Marc Bator, Tagesschau 20:00, 24.01.2021 [*Antik**ö**rpermedikamente*](https://www.tagesschau.de/multimedia/sendung/ts-41161.html)@20:14:40

Comment: Are the Northern Germans you're referring to from a certain region? I come from the North and would put the main stress on the "A" as well. Hence I'm wondering, whether the stress on the "o" is specific for a  specific region/dialect.

Comment: I hear it often from Hamburg people like the Tagesschausprecher, Anne Will and the like, that very example was from todays Münster-Tatort from Thiel. So it seems to be really widespread. In TV it seems to me it even becomes standard (TV is pretty dominated by northern Speakers).

Comment: 1) You know you can post in German here, right? 2) I was born in Schleswig-Holstein  and now live in Baden, and I have no idea what you are talking about, sorry. I have never heard anyone stress Alterswohnsitz on the third syllable, except when the "wohnsitz" part needed to be stressed in the context of the sentence. More examples, please, if possible.Maybe a link to a youtube video or something`like that?

Comment: Ich habe das Beispiel angeführt, aber habe gerade bemerkt, dass hier der Wechsel der Betonung intendiert sein könnte um zu betonen dass er Ruhe wollte aber Stress bekommen hat. Das wäre ein Fall wo ich die Betonungsänderung verstehe. Ich suche jetzt andere Beispiele wo das nicht durch die Intention gerechtfertigt ist. Aber das Prinzip wäre das selbe, würden wir annehmen es ginge nicht dezidiert um die Ruhe.

Comment: Sorry, wirklich schlechtes Beispiel. Es hilft mir jedenfalls nicht, mich an Fälle zu erinnern, wo dich unterschiedliche Betonungen in Nord- und Süddeutsch beobachtet hätte. (Ich bin in Mitteldeutschland zu Hause)

Comment: Somewhat related: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/30090/1626

Comment: @phipsgabler It would work already with Buchhalter: Búchhalter (correct) vs Buchhàlter (strange).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This observation uses an ill-fitting example. But the observation is not entirely unfounded, albeit such consistently differing stresses are *not* restricted to composita:

A [short list of examples is found here:](http://www.bairische-sprache.at/Index/Remaraweng%20Boarisch%20-%20Lehren/Merkmale.htm)

> 3. Die Vermeidung der nieder- und angelsächsischen Betonung
>
> Nord-Hochdeutsch
> Süd-Hochdeutsch
>
> *Kon*sum Kon*sum*
> […]
>
> 4. Die Abneigung gegen barsche Betonung
>
> Nord-Hochdeutsch Süd- Hochdeutsch
>
> *Ta*bak Ta*bak*
>
> *Kaff*ee Kaf*fee*
> […]

For an in-depth lexicon on this theme of pluricentricity within the German laguage confer to

> Einfache Wörter, die weder zusammengesetzt noch abgeleitet sind, werden im Deutschen in allen Regionen auf der ersten Silbe oder auf der Stammsilbe betont. Dagegen gibt es nationale und regionale Besonderheiten bei Zusammensetzungen und Ableitungen. Wenn die erste Silbe nicht zugleich die Stammsilbe ist, so wird von Fall zu Fall die Erstsilbe oder die Stammsilbe betont. In Österreich und der Schweiz, aber auch im südlichen Deutschland neigt man stärker zur Erstsilbenbetonung, im nördlichen Deutschland stärker zur Stammsilbenbetonung (z. B. *un*glaublich gegenüber un*glaub*lich), wobei dieser Gegensatz keineswegs bei allen entsprechenden Wörtern auftritt. Auch bei Lehn- und Fremdwörtern kann man ähnliche Unterschiede beobachten: Erstsilbenbetonung im Süden gegenüber Zweit- oder Drittsilbenbetonung im Norden (z. B. *A*nis gegenüber A*nis*). Den umgekehrten Fall der Zweitsilbenbetonung im Süden gegenüber Erstsilbenbetonung im Norden findet man seltener (z. B. in Mo*tor* gegenüber *Mo*tor, O*rient* gegenüber *O*rient).
> […]
> In der Satzbetonung ist auffällig, dass bei einer Verbindung von Präposition und Pronomen in Österreich das Pronomen, in Deutschland die Präposition betont wird (z. B. etwas von *sich* geben; ich komm zu *dir*.)
> <sub>— Ulrich Ammon, Hans Bickel, and Alexandra Nicole Lenz: "Variantenwörterbuch des Deutschen. German Dictionary of Regional Language Variants
> Die Standardsprache in Österreich, der Schweiz, Deutschland, Liechtenstein, Luxemburg, Ostbelgien und Südtirol sowie Rumänien, Namibia und Mennonitensiedlungen", De Gruyter: Berlin, <sup>2</sup>2016 [doi](https://doi-org.wwwdb.dbod.de/10.1515/9783110245448).</sub>

Comment: Danke für die erhellenden Beispiele, die der Fragesteller nicht liefern konnte.

Comment: @Wolf :Ich bin keine Maschine und davon ausgegangen, dass ich noch etwas Zeit bekomme. Das studenlange Sichten von Videomaterial benötigt eben Stunden die ich nicht am Stück entbehren kann.Ich bin dran und werde etwas liefen, es kann aber noch die ein oder andere Woche dauern. Ich fühle mich dennoch willkommen auf dieser Seite.

Comment: @Rudi_Birnbaum Keine Panik. 'Zeit' ist relativ unendlich und lediglich ein kleineres Allokationsproblem in der Praxis. Solange diese Seite nicht abgeschaltet wird: kaum ein posting ist jemals 'fertig' ;)

Comment: @Rudi_Birnbaum Kein Problem, wer kennt das nicht. Andererseits hättest du dir mir der Frage vielleicht auch noch etwas Zeit lassen können. Wie auch immer: Willkommen im Club :)

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly a misunderstanding. Or just a really bad choice for an example.<sup>[1]</sup>

At this point in the film, the emphasis on the word *Ruhe* (Engl: *rest*) in the word *Altersruhesitz* (Engl: *old-age retirement home*) is indeed unmistakable. But behind it there is no regional peculiarity of the speaker. Rather, the speaker wants to express that the prospect of rest in old age for the person being talked about was ultimately not fulfilled.

By the way: this question would have been easier to answer if it had been asked in German.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> You stated: *I could give plenty of other examples for that.* -- so there is hope for a change?

Comment: Assume it's not a misunderstanding and the stress would be the same. I will give other examples, but don't expect surprises, it will be exactly the same in terms of stress. I will check Anne Wills talks, she does it often. Sorry for the English. As I started with it I bring it to the bitter end.

Answer (score 0):

I am also a Bavarian and I have lived in Braunschweig (Prussia/Lower Saxony or northern Germany) for almost 5 years. At no point did I notice that my Prussian/northern colleagues would *consistently* use stress differently from me, the Bavarian. Exceptions exist, for example nobody immediately understood *Ánisplatzerl* but instead insisted on *Anísplätzchen*, but in practically all other cases I observed no difference in the use of stress in compound words.