# Warum "buchhalterisch" auf der vorletzten Silbe betonen?

Tags: etymology, pronunciation

Warum wird *buchhalterisch* manchmal auch gleich noch so stark auf der vorletzten Silbe betont, so als wollte es sich auf *Tee* reimen? [1]

Das habe ich zuweilen nur von wenigen Leuten, dann aber besonders deutlich gehört.

Ein ähnliches Beispiel ist *gerechtfêrtigt* anstelle *gerèchtfertigt* oder so. *Vorhérsage* betone ich selbst ganz komisch, laut Duden online aber korrekt auf der zweiten Silbe. Angenommen die Ursachen seien vergleichbar, wäre eine allgemeinere Antwort wünschenswert.

Andernfalls geht es immerhin um "b**u**chhalterisch" mit Hinblick auf die Betonung, denn es sollte laut Duden eigentlich auf der Ersten betont werden. Und was ist das überhaupt für ein Wort, ähnlich *Platzhalter*; wie lautet die Betonung ursprünglich!?

PS: Dies ist kein Duplikat zu der bereits bestehenden Frage, [Wie wird das Adjektiv zum Buchhalter richtig betont](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/30090/wie-wird-das-adjektiv-zum-buchhalter-richtig-betont). Dort wird nach einer praeskriptiven Vorschrift gefragt. Meine Frage stellt jedoch auf die Herkunft ab. Die dort gegebenen Antworten sind ohnehin nicht verbindlich. Allenfalls ohne Anspruch auf Richtigkeit ist *kommentiert* worden, dass bspw. die Buchhalter selbst es auf *Tee* betonen.

[1]: Ich muss davon ausgehen, dass es irgendwer schonmal gehört hat oder sich zumindest etwas darunter vorstellen kann.

Comment: Könnte es ein Regionaldialekt sein, vielleicht aus Hessen? Zumindest daher kenne ich eine Person, die in manchen Worten ein sehr breites langes _e_ spricht. Das Pronomen _es_ wird dann eher wie der Plural vom Buchstaben E _Es_ ausgesprochen.

Comment: Ansonsten würde ich hieraus zwei Fragen machen. Einmal nach der e Aussprache und einmal nach der Herkunft von Buchhalter.

Comment: DWDS gibt sowohl [ˈbuːχhaltəʀɪʃ] als auch [buːχhal'teːʀɪʃ] als korrekte Aussprache an. Das [Aussprachebeispiel](https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?title=File%3ADe-buchhalterisch2.ogg) im Wikimedia ist [buːχhal'teːʀɪʃ].

Comment: Der "Stadthalter" ist genau das eben nicht, weil er nicht eine "Stadt" hält, sondern irgendwas an**statt** seines Herrschers (bzw.: für diesen). Deshalb heißt er auch richtigerweise "Statthalter".

Comment: Der *Stadthalter* sollte eigentlich ein *Platzhalter* für eine ganze Reihe von Worten sein.